# Solving a Maze Using Queue in Java

Tags: java, queue

My homework is to determine if a maze is solvable of not using Queue. If it is, print the path. I can get Queue to get to the end but it says it's unsolvable. When actually it is. If I change the Final check if Statement to:

```
if (queue.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("The maze is solvable!");
    }
else
    {
        System.out.println("The maze is unsolvable!");
    }
```

Then it says it is solvable, but then when I try another maze that isn't solvable it says it is solvable. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

I have a separate Point class that defines the Points and right, left, above and below positions. I have to use Point (0,0) to mark the start and Point (row-1,col-1) to mark the goal.

Let me know if you need more code. It is searching a char 2D array.

**maze1.txt - (First Line Defines the # of Rows and Columns) - Is Solvable**

```
7 12
..+.+.++++++
.++...++...+
..++.....+.+
+.+..++.+..+
+...++....++
+.+++..++..+
++++++++++..
```

**Says it's unsolvable**

```
    QueueMaze
The maze is unsolvable!
p p + p + p + + + + + + 
p + + p p p + + p p p + 
p p + + p p p p p + p + 
+ p + p p + + p + p p + 
+ p p p + + p p p p + + 
+ p + + + p p + + p p + 
+ + + + + + + + + + p .
```

**mMethod for solving the Maze**

```
public void queueMaze() {

char[][] storedMaze = copy(); 

LinkedList<Point> queue = new LinkedList<Point>();
    int count = 0;
    Point start = new Point(0,0);
    Point cur, end, above, right, left, below;

    Boolean solved = false;

queue.add(start); 

while (!queue.isEmpty())
    {
    //Store the first element position 0 in cur
        cur = queue.removeFirst();
        //System.out.println(cur.toString());

        //compare cur's points to the isEnd points
        //(row-1, col-1) if it is the end, break out
        //of the While
        if (isEnd(cur) && isSafe(cur))
        {
            //System.out.println("cur's final : " + cur.toString());
            end = cur;
            break;
        }

        //mark cur as visited with a P
    markVisited(cur, P);

        //check the position above cur to see if it is
        //
    right = cur.getRight(); 
    if (inBounds(right) && isSafe(right))
        {
            queue.add(right);
        }

        below = cur.getBelow(); 
    if (inBounds(below) && isSafe(below))
        {
            queue.add(below);
        }

        left = cur.getLeft(); 
    if (inBounds(left) && isSafe(left))
        {
            queue.add(left);
        }

        above = cur.getAbove(); 
    if (inBounds(above) && isSafe(above))
        {
            queue.add(above);
        }

}//while
//System.out.println("The queue size is: " + queue.size());

    if (!queue.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("The maze is solvable!");
    }
else
    {
        System.out.println("The maze is unsolvable!");
    }

print();

returnMaze(storedMaze);
}
```

Comment: depth first search is your friend.

Comment: Doesn't depth first search use Stack? I have to use Queue which is similar to Breadth-first search right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Stuck in a Maze using Stack/Queue in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113222/getting-stuck-in-a-maze-using-stack-queue-in-java)

Comment: I posted both questions. But the other question was using stack and this is using Queue. I got the other one figured out and answered it. I didn't want to add to it because it would become bigger then it already was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the queue being empty does not determine whether or not the maze is solved. the queue simply keeps track of which spaces still need to be checked. it is perfectly fine to come to the end of the maze with lots of spaces left to check in your queue.

it looks like if your `if (isEnd(cur) && isSafe(cur))`  is triggered, then the maze is solveable.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That is right and that's where I tried to end it. But if I remove the if(!queue.isEmpty())... statement outside the while loop and put the print out in the if (isEnd(cur) && isSafe(cur)) that it was successful, it works for a solvable maze. But I can't figure out to get it to print "it's Unsolvable" if it breaks out of the while without triggering the isEnd?

Comment: `boolean solved = false; while (loop) { if (isEnd(cur) && isSafe(cur)) { solved = true; } } if (solved) { /* solveable */ } else { /* unsolveable */ }`

Comment: It's working using that. I added a break; to the if(solved) section. But until it is solved or unsolved it keeps getting caught by the else and printing out unsolved. I'm going to see if I can stop that. Somehow I need to return a true for solved from the while that will be caught outside of the while. Then I can have a if outside that will say not solvable anytime it kicks out anything except a true because solved is initialized as false.

Comment: I got it. Initialized solved=false in the MazeArray class and then created a method that returns solved=true and it's solvable. if (isEnd(cur) && isSafe(cur)) is true, then runs that method. I added a method outside of the while(loop) that says if solved=false, it's unsolvable. Works with all mazes. Thank you!